# How can I access <li> tags one by one in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

I have various `<li>` elements in a label in my aspx page. I want to use Javascript to fetch one `<li>` element at a time and perform some action on it. I have no idea how to do it;
which function should I use?

Earlier I got a list for the same in C#, but I can't iterate over it in Javascript, so I converted it to `<li>` so that it can be accessed by Javascript.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify and include a code example. Capitalization and proper punctuation are plusses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    //manipulate them how?
    console.log(li[i]);

}
```

how are you trying to manipulate them? what would you do, this will insert them into an array called li and the for loop will cycle through. but what is it you want to do?

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/yTXuK/

Answer (score 1):

Use document.getElementsByTagName("li")

This would return a collection of li's

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery you can use a basic selector to get a jquery object containing the lis of `<li>`s and then you can act upon them with each.

```
$('li').each(function(){  
    var li = $(this);
    //code to manipulate li
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('li')` will return an array of li elements.

Edit:
You could optionally add an array of the data points to the page by printing out a script tag on the page instead of the li's. That way you don't have extra unneeded elements on the page.

Comment: u mean -> var[] varName = document.getElementByTagName('li');

Comment: no var narName = document.getElementsByTagName("li"). There isn't a [] in the var name and the getElements is plural

Comment: it would just be var varName = document.getElementbyTagName('li');

Comment: Technically, it's a NodeList, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```